# finding out redundancy

Tags: sql

I have a foreign table...and I wanna see the redundant rows corresponding to the foreign column and also the number of redundancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select foriegn_column_name,COUNT(foriegn_column_name) from table_name
group by foriegn_column_name
having COUNT(foriegn_column_name) > 1
```